# Discrepancy in task run per map with the tasks configured in mapred-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I stopped all the agents running in my pseudo distributed mode by giving the following command.

```
stop-all.sh
```

Then I changed the configuration file of  "mapred-site.xml" to 1 Map Task

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

you see I have set 1 MapTask snd 1 ReduceTask to run.

Then I started back all the agents

```
start-all.sh
```

and run the map-reduce program but still I see 2 tasks instead of 1 as configured in mapred-site.xml.

The screen shot of the tasks are shown below,

[image]

Why is such discrepancy occurring, Please guide me through

thanks

Comment: Please read the documentation FIRST and then ask question. You are limiting the number of tasks that can run at the same time.

Comment: Thomas, I am trying to understand the scenario not performance tune it. I just want to know If my understanding is right or wrong. A straight forward answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this property mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum tells the maximum number of tasks (mapper tasks) which can be run by a task tracker at a time. Basically you are restricting each node running task tracker to run one mapper at a time.

If you have 10 nodes then you should be able to run 10 mappers in parallel.

However if your job requires 2 mappers (which is totally based on size of input data & block size unless you extend inputformat) and you have only one node then the map tasks would be executed sequentially on that node.

Hope this is clearer now.

Comment: Thanks I get It, The actual problem was something else I'll try making it clear in my next question, Please do provide your valuable insights on that one too.